# Is the intersection of two intervals again an interval?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected graph,
where $V$ is the set of nodes and $E$ is the set of edges.

A (finite) [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory))
in $G$ is a sequence $(v_i)^n_{i=0}$ in $V$
such that $\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}$ is an edge, i.e. lies in $E$, for $i=0,\ldots,n-1$,
and the nodes are all distinct.
A path $(v_i)^n_{i=0}$ is said to be from $a$ to $b$ if $v_0 = a$ and $v_n = b$.

Let's define the union of all shortest paths from $a$ to $b$
as the set of all nodes of those paths,
and call it the interval from $a$ to $b$
and denote it by $[a,b]$.

**Question**:
Is the intersection of two intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ again an interval,
i.e., of the form $[e,f]$ for some nodes $e$ and $f$,
or the empty set?

I don't really know how start here.
If the setting would be that of a partially ordered set $(X,\leq)$,
and an interval $[a,b]$ would be a set $\{x\in X:a\leq x\leq b\}$,
then I would have some intuition how to tackle this.
Does anyone have a hint on how to start?

Comment: What do you mean by union of paths?

Comment: @5xum I mean their union as sets: if $(v_i)^m_{i=0}$ and $(w_j)^n_{j=0}$ are paths, then their union is the set $\{v_0,\ldots,v_m,w_0,\ldots,w_n\}$. Sorry for the unclearity.

Comment: @5xum I edited the question to incorporate what I mean by union of paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not in general. Consider the bipartite graph $K_{2,4}$, with $\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\}$ being the part of cardinal $4$ and $\{u,v\}$ the other part. Then $[a_1,b_1] \cap [a_2,b_2] = \{u,v\}$ is not an interval.

Comment: Thanks! Your example helped me realise that the same can be said for partially ordered sets. Viewing $K_{2,4}$ as the Hasse diagram of a partially ordered set $(X,\leq)$ with $a_1$ and $a_2$ below and $b_1$ and $b_2$ above $u$ and $v$, and defining intervals in $(X,\leq)$ by $[a,b]=\{x\in X:a\leq x\leq b\}$, yields also here that $[a_1,b_1]\cap[a_2,b_2]=\{u,v\}$ is not an interval. So also in partially ordered sets the intersection of two intervals in general is not an interval.